# Can the leaked AmigaOS after-3.1 source code be referred to?

Tags: discussion

Last year there was been a widespread leak of AmigaOS's source code after released version 3.1. Are we allowed to refer to files in that archive (say, by writing a file's path in the archive)?

Answer (score 3):

I would be careful with linking to or posting any sections of that leaked codebase, no matter how small.  In an [official statement](http://hyperion-entertainment.biz/index.php/news/38-corporate/167-amigaos-31-source-code-leak-official-statement), Hyperion Entertainment said they would "examine all possible legal action against any unauthorized source of or use of this material it is aware of."

We should not allow any section of this code on Retrocomputing.  Referring to a file path *may* be acceptable if and only if absolutely necessary.  We should avoid referencing the codebase at all to avoid any legal action from Hyperion towards Stack Exchange.

Related: [What should we do about (potential) copyright infringement?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/194/621)