# Can I ask and answer questions related to the Infinity Game Boy Color source code?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently, Affinix Software released the [incomplete source code](https://github.com/infinity-gbc/infinity) for their Game Boy Color game Infinity.  Most of the source code and graphics is licensed under Noncommercial Creative Commons except for the audio data which is licensed by the  No Derivatives version of Creative Commons.

Since this release is intentional and not a leak like the [AmigaOS source](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/621), I think we should be able to discuss the codebase and how to build it.

Can we discuss the Infinity Game Boy Color codebase?  I have asked an initial question about one of the project's dependencies [here](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1389/621).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why not. The code, while having been released recently, is old enough to be considered retro, and your question about the source code hasn't been badly received. The only thing stopping us using the AmigaOS source is that it is a leak, and this is a perfectly legitimate release.

So yes, I think you can ask and answer questions related to the Infinity Game Boy Colour codebase.